# NSTableView editable cell deselects edit more randomly

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a cell-based NSTableView with an editable text field. Sometimes, seemingly randomly, after choosing to edit the field and typing a few characters, the field exits edit mode and I am left unable to edit the value.

Closing the document and reopening fixes it for a while.

What might be causing this?

It is bound to an NSArrayController and I believe that NSConditionallySetsEditableBindingOption is true by default.

Comment: Anything might be causing this. Tip: Create a [mre] to find the cause.

Comment: Hard to do as it is in a rather complex app but only being reported by one customer. It is in a cell-based Table, but a view-Based Table becomes unable to edit in the same app once it gets into this mode. I am never calling reloadTable.

Comment: Wild guess ('cause it happened to me): is there any possibility that the data model (the array) is getting mutated while you're editing?

Comment: I don't think so - there are background threads that import the data into the array and that was something I had thought of, but the data is fully imported so should not be changed during the edit as far as I can tell.

Comment: Update: The customer also has PathFinder, TextExpander and Keyboard Maestro (not sure if those might be related). The edit mode only stays alive for a second or so, then drops out and the Table is no longer the First Responder, though the row that was highlights remains so in grey. The Responder chain is then broken - nothing after the TableView remains in the Responder chain as the TableView becomes the last item in the chain... it does allow the responder to go back to the beginning with the tab key.

Comment: You say "the customer" ... is this happening to you, or someone else? If it's you, try registering an observer to the "end editing" notification or attach a delegate to that field, then set a breakpoint on that event and when it happens again try to figure out what caused it or is happening at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately it is only happening on a customer's machine and I can't duplicate it here. After disabling PathFInder, TextExpander and Keyboard Maestro the problem persists. I don't mind building a custom version of the software with some error logging specific to this.

Comment: UPDATE: It works fine with Xcode 11 at optimization settings of -O0, -O1, -O2 and -O3, but exhibits the bug with -Os. The code analyzer does not reveal any issues and I still can't reproduce it locally.